# How to enforce function call signature in typescript when the compiler can't infer it automatically

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two functions that are related by some means (let's say remote procedure call) that can't be infered by the compiler.

```
//on the server
RandomFramework.declareHandler("foobarHandler", (foo: Foo, bar: Bar)=>{
   //do stuff
});
```

```
//on the client 
RandomFramework.call("fooBarHandler", foo, baz); //baz is of type Baz instead of Bar
```

How do I enforce the call signature of my remote procedure ?

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to say. You can share types definitions between the server and client, but that may require RandomFramework to support generic types (so that e.g. `RandomFramework.call<SomeType>(...)` could be paired with the same on the other side).

Answer (score 0):

@jonsharpe is correct. You would need to define a type like this:

```
type CustomFunction = (foo: Foo, bar: Bar) => void;
```

and your call function would have to be defined something like this:

type CustomFunction = (foo: Foo, bar: Bar) => void;

```
class RandomFramework {
  public static call = <T extends (...args: any) => any>(key: string, ...args: Parameters<T>) => {
    // do something
  };
}
```

And then you call it:

```
RandomFramework.call<CustomFunction>('fooBarHandler', foo, baz) // error because baz is not correct type
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, i will look into adding the types to the Framework.
I was hoping there was an "inline" way to enforce it while calling my function.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there isn't. Closest to that wpuld be if you created discriminated union type where ypu would need to define key value pairs in advance, where key would be the name of the function and value its signature. But that beats the point of your "dynamic" observer pattern